# Password Changer using VAccess

Tags: vb6, pervasive

Hey I am working on a password changer. User logs in ( successfully), loads a global var with user initials, then launch a password expired form. I try and use those initials on the password expired form to retrieve user info from DB.

```
vaUserLog.FieldValue("USERINIT") = UserInitials
vaUserLog.GetEqual
vaStat = vaUserLog.Status
```

vaStat keeps giving me an error of 4. I am using pervasive v9. Connection with VA looks like:

```
With vaUserLog
        .RefreshLocations = True
        .DdfPath = DataPath
        .TableName = "USERLOG"
        .Location = "USERLOG.MKD"
        .Open
        If .Status <> 0 Then
           ErrMsg = "Error Opening File " + .TableName + " - Status " + str$(.Status) + vbCrLf + "Contact IT Department"
        End If
    End With
```

In DB table, USERINIT is Char, 3. UserInitials is a String.

Probably missing something small but can't think right now. Any help is appreciate. Lemme know if you require more info.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status 4 means that the record could not be found.  In your case, it could be the case of the value being searched is wrong, there's a different padding (spaces versus binary zero), or that the UserInitials value just isn't in the data file. 
You can use [MKDE Tracing](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=advops/configref.4.7.html) to see what's actually being passed to the PSQL engine.  Once you've done that, make sure the value you're using works through the [Function Executor](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=advops/funcexec.12.1.html) where you can open the file and perform a GetEqual.
Here are my suggestions:
- Make sure you're pointing to the right data files.
- Make sure you're passing the right value into the GetEqual (by setting the FieldValue).

Comment: Hmm alright, so I made sure I was pointing to the right data. Had PCC open and ensured that data was in there. I also tried switching to the USERID, which actually worked. Only diff between the 2 fields in the DB are the length of Char lol I'm baffled.

Comment: I just noticed something else that might be causing this.  I don't see where you're setting the index to be used for the GetEqual.  If you haven't changed it to the USERINT field, then a status 4 would probably occur.